# Не читаются картинки

Tags: html, css, изображения, background

HTML:

```
<div class = "contacts">
  <ul>
    <li class = "contsctsCoordinates">Ростовская область, г. Волгодонск, ул. Карла Маркса, 24<br>Индекс: 347383</li>
    <li class = "contsctsPhone">8 (8639) 23-15-29,<br>23-65-27,<br>23-15-44</li>
    <li class = "contsctsMail">nsh-28@yandex.ru</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contacts {
  float: left;
  margin: 45px 20px;
 }
.contsctsCoordinates {
    background: url("/img/icon-coordinates.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
}
.contsctsPhone {
    background: url("/img/icon-phone.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
}
.contsctsMail {
    background: url("/img/icon-mail.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
.contsctsCoordinates, .contsctsPhone, .contsctsMail {
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    background-size: 27px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил вставить CSS-код, чтобы видно было.

Comment: вот Вам репутация. Можете вставлять ссылки.

Comment: Где лежат картинки по отношению к корню сайта, по отношению к css файлу?

Comment: Разобрался. Запутался в директориях... Туплю на глазах просто)